Error creating ASP.NET migration due to multiple foreign key constraints
I'm facing a problem creating the initial migration for my ASP.NET project. After defining models and data annotations, when trying to create the database, I encounter the following error in the NuGet Console:
Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [FCT] (
    [IdFCT] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [AlunoIdAluno] int NOT NULL,
    [EmpresaIdEmpresa] int NOT NULL,
    [InstituicaoEnsinoIdInstituicao] int NOT NULL,
    [DataInicioFCT] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [DataFimFCT] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [PeriodoFCTIdPeriodo] int NOT NULL,
    [AvaliacaoIdAvaliacao] int NOT NULL,
    [DocumentosIdDocumento] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_FCT] PRIMARY KEY ([IdFCT]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_FCT_Alunos_AlunoIdAluno] FOREIGN KEY ([AlunoIdAluno]) REFERENCES [Alunos] ([IdAluno]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_FCT_Avaliacao_AvaliacaoIdAvaliacao] FOREIGN KEY ([AvaliacaoIdAvaliacao]) REFERENCES [Avaliacao] ([IdAvaliacao]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_FCT_Documentos_DocumentosIdDocumento] FOREIGN KEY ([DocumentosIdDocumento]) REFERENCES [Documentos] ([IdDocumento]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_FCT_Empresa_EmpresaIdEmpresa] FOREIGN KEY ([EmpresaIdEmpresa]) REFERENCES [Empresa] ([IdEmpresa]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_FCT_InstituicaoEnsino_InstituicaoEnsinoIdInstituicao] FOREIGN KEY ([InstituicaoEnsinoIdInstituicao]) REFERENCES [InstituicaoEnsino] ([IdInstituicao]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_FCT_PeriodoFCT_PeriodoFCTIdPeriodo] FOREIGN KEY ([PeriodoFCTIdPeriodo]) REFERENCES [PeriodoFCT] ([IdPeriodo]) ON DELETE CASCADE

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_FCT_InstituicaoEnsino_InstituicaoEnsinoIdInstituicao' on table 'FCT' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Here are my Models (the ones that I think that are causing the problem):
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FCTConnect.Models
{
    public class FCT
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdFCT { get; set; }

        public Aluno Aluno { get; set; }

        public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

        public InstituicaoEnsino InstituicaoEnsino { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DataInicioFCT { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DataFimFCT { get; set; }

        public PeriodoFCT PeriodoFCT { get; set; }

        public Avaliacao Avaliacao { get; set; }

        public Documentos Documentos { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FCTConnect.Models
{
    public class Aluno
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdAluno { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Idade { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Curso { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Phone]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Morada { get; set; }

        public InstituicaoEnsino InstituicaoEnsino { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace FCTConnect.Models
{
    public class InstituicaoEnsino
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdInstituicao { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Morada { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Phone]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }
}

In the previous phase, I develop the following E-R Diagram:
e-r diagram
My project is being developed in Visual Studio with the SQL Server.
I'm grateful to anyone who can help.
I tried to specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION but I was unsuccessful.
I tried defining foreign keys instead of declaring classes directly, but I think that declaring classes directly will be more advantageous in program development.

I noticed that you have this class in your code:
public class FCT
{
    [Key]
    public int IdFCT { get; set; }

    public Aluno Aluno { get; set; }

    public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

    public InstituicaoEnsino InstituicaoEnsino { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataInicioFCT { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataFimFCT { get; set; }

    public PeriodoFCT PeriodoFCT { get; set; }

    public Avaliacao Avaliacao { get; set; }

    public Documentos Documentos { get; set; }
}

Here, you a variable called public Aluno Aluno of type Aluno which is another class in your code. So, have a foreign Key reference the primary key of the Aluno class and the same as InstituicaoEnsino class. So maybe the error will go away if you code like this and write explicitly the relationship between the classes :
    public int IdAluno { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("IdAluno")]
    public Aluno Aluno { get; set; }

    public int IdInstituicao { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("IdInstituicao")]
    public InstituicaoEnsino InstituicaoEnsino { get; set; }

Try adding the foreign key to respective classes that you have written and take reference of this example, it's important to pinpoint accurately what the primary and foreign keys are, and which key references which table. See whether this works. If not, give more information on what classes you have and what tables you have. Try if it works.

Hello user24731489. Thanks for your help. I already tried to add foreign keys on my classes references but the same error happens. To solve this problem I removed the     public InstituicaoEnsino InstituicaoEnsino { get; set; } declaration. My Aluno class as an InstituicaoEnsino call to so I think if I want to call InstituicaoEnsino in FCT class, I can do that by calling Aluno.InstituicaoEnsino. Am I thinking correctly?

Keep the foreign keys for each table you have and have one foreign key referenced for each table in the class and then when you are calling the FCT class by ef core or by sql connection and dapper, include the classes with keyword include like this example which I have used for for my repositories where address and department are different tables - _context.Tbl_Employee.Include(e => e.Address).Include(e => e.Department).ToList(); or use inner join or left join to get the data if you are using sql connection and dapper
